# What is the exact difference between DropdownMenu & DropdownButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Both of the widgets look almost similar. So, what is the exact use case of them? Also, how do you set the width of the DropdownMenu, not the entries?

Comment: A dropdown menu allows you to filter the list according to what you are searching for. It is attached with a Textfield where the user can type the word and the drop-down will be filtered according to what the user has written.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, `DropdownMenu` is an updated version of `DropdownButton` that follows the Material 3 specification.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

- `DropdownMenu` is a stateless widget that represents the drop-down menu itself. It does not have any state of its own, and it depends on the DropdownButton widget to provide the list of items and the currently selected item.
- `DropdownButton` is a stateful widget that represents the drop-down button itself. It has state for the list of items, the currently selected item, and the on-change callback.

In other words, `DropdownMenu` is a "dumb" widget that just displays the drop-down menu, while `DropdownButton` is a "smart" widget that handles the logic of displaying the list of items, selecting an item, and calling the on-change callback.